# REST&GAE: How to define a getter without using resource Id

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am using Google App Engine with Cloud Endpoints to code a simple API. That API only has one entity: Book, with fields Long id and String name.

The Google Plugin for Eclipse generated for me an API class which has a getBook(Long id) method. However, I would also like to be able to get a book knowing its name. That is to say I would like to also have a getBookByName(String name) method. Could you show me a simple code for it, or a link which shows something like that? I think I have to use the JDO framework with a query object.

Here is the API class code:

```
@Api(name = "bookendpoint")
public class BookEndpoint {
/**
 * This method lists all the entities inserted in datastore.
 * It uses HTTP GET method and paging support.
 *
 * @return A CollectionResponse class containing the list of all entities
 * persisted and a cursor to the next page.
 */
@SuppressWarnings({ "unchecked", "unused" })
@ApiMethod(name = "listBook")
public CollectionResponse<Book> listBook(
        @Nullable @Named("cursor") String cursorString,
        @Nullable @Named("limit") Integer limit) {

    PersistenceManager mgr = null;
    Cursor cursor = null;
    List<Book> execute = null;

    try {
        mgr = getPersistenceManager();
        Query query = mgr.newQuery(Book.class);
        if (cursorString != null && cursorString != "") {
            cursor = Cursor.fromWebSafeString(cursorString);
            HashMap<String, Object> extensionMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            extensionMap.put(JDOCursorHelper.CURSOR_EXTENSION, cursor);
            query.setExtensions(extensionMap);
        }

        if (limit != null) {
            query.setRange(0, limit);
        }

        execute = (List<Book>) query.execute();
        cursor = JDOCursorHelper.getCursor(execute);
        if (cursor != null)
            cursorString = cursor.toWebSafeString();

        // Tight loop for fetching all entities from datastore and accomodate
        // for lazy fetch.
        for (Book obj : execute)
            ;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }

    return CollectionResponse.<Book> builder().setItems(execute)
            .setNextPageToken(cursorString).build();
}

/**
 * This method gets the entity having primary key id. It uses HTTP GET method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the java bean.
 * @return The entity with primary key id.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "getBook")
public Book getBook(@Named("id") Long id) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    Book book = null;
    try {
        book = mgr.getObjectById(Book.class, id);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return book;
}
/**
 * This inserts a new entity into App Engine datastore. If the entity already
 * exists in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP POST method.
 *
 * @param book the entity to be inserted.
 * @return The inserted entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "insertBook")
public Book insertBook(Book book) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if (book.getId() != null) {
        if (containsBook(book)) {
            throw new EntityExistsException("Object already exists");
        }
        }
        mgr.makePersistent(book);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return book;
}

/**
 * This method is used for updating an existing entity. If the entity does not
 * exist in the datastore, an exception is thrown.
 * It uses HTTP PUT method.
 *
 * @param book the entity to be updated.
 * @return The updated entity.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "updateBook")
public Book updateBook(Book book) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        if (!containsBook(book)) {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException("Object does not exist");
        }
        mgr.makePersistent(book);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return book;
}

/**
 * This method removes the entity with primary key id.
 * It uses HTTP DELETE method.
 *
 * @param id the primary key of the entity to be deleted.
 */
@ApiMethod(name = "removeBook")
public void removeBook(@Named("id") Long id) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    try {
        Book book = mgr.getObjectById(Book.class, id);
        mgr.deletePersistent(book);
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
}

private boolean containsBook(Book book) {
    PersistenceManager mgr = getPersistenceManager();
    boolean contains = true;
    try {
        mgr.getObjectById(Book.class, book.getId());
    } catch (javax.jdo.JDOObjectNotFoundException ex) {
        contains = false;
    } finally {
        mgr.close();
    }
    return contains;
}

private static PersistenceManager getPersistenceManager() {
    return PMF.get().getPersistenceManager();
}
}
```

Comment: post that API class code please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overloading is not supported. You should just call your functions "getBookByName", "getBookByISBN", etc...

Comment: Yes it seems so. However I asked for a simple code to retrieve a book knowing only its name.

Comment: Am I missing something? There's no hidden secret method, it sounds like you just need a query on the name property. Look into JPQL, which is how queries are written in JPA framework.[1]

[1] - http://www.objectdb.com/java/jpa/query/jpql/structure

Comment: Yes I only need to query on the name property. However I'm not using JPA but JDO.

Comment: Oh hey, apologies for missing that. Here, [try this](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jdo/queries) - this is the first result when I search google for "JDO query by property" - it's an App Engine docs page. This is exactly what you need. Look at the section "filters" for the operator `==`